# SEd: replace whitespace characters with single comma except inside quotes

Tags: regex, sed

This line is from a car dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG)
looking like this:

```
15.0   8.   429.0      198.0      4341.      10.0   70.  1.     "ford galaxie 500"
```

how would one replace the multiple whitespace (it has both space and tabs) w/ a single comma, but not inside the quotes, preferably using sed,to turn the dataset into a REAL csv. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916159/sed-replace-spaces-within-quotes-with-underscores

Comment: what do you already try that failed ?

Comment: I tried,
$ sed 's/[^"] [^"]//g'  data/auto-mpg.data-original
$ sed 's/[^"][ \t][^"]/,/g'  data/auto-mpg.data-original

$ sed 's/[^"][ \t]*[^"]/,/g'  data/auto-mpg.data-original

$ sed 's/[^"][ \t][^"]/,/g'  data/auto-mpg.data-original

$ sed 's/[ \t]/,/g;s/,,,//g'  data/auto-mpg.data

$ sed 's/[ \t]/,/g'  data/auto-mpg.data

$ perl -pe 's/"(.+?[^\\])"/($ret = $1) =~ (s#,##g); $ret/ge' data/auto-mpg.data
$ sed 's/\(.*"\),/\1 /'  data/auto-mpg.data
$ sed 's/\(.*\"\),/\1 /g'  data/auto-mpg.data-commad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it with awk:

```
awk -F'"' 'BEGIN { OFS="\"" } { for(i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) { gsub(/[ \t]+/, ",", $i); } print }' filename.csv
```

Using `"` as the field separator, every second field is going to be a part of the line where spaces should be replaced. Then:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }               # output should also be separated by "
{
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) {  # in every second field
    gsub(/[ \t]+/, ",", $i)      # replace spaces with commas
  }
  print                          # and print the whole shebang
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will let you know after getting the chance to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\("[^"]*"\|[0-9.]*\)\s\s*/\1,/g' file
```

This takes a quoted string or a decimal number followed by white space and replaces the white space by a comma - throughout each and every line.

To be less specific use (as per comments):

```
sed -r 's/("[^"]*"|\S+)\s+/\1,/g' file
```

Comment: That confused some of my test inputs, and I drew false conclusions at first (sorry about the first comment). There's a typo in your pattern: the closing paren should be escaped, and may I suggest to replace `[0-9.]` with `[^[:space:]]` to make it work with non-numeric unquoted tokens? That is: `s/\("[^"]*"\|[^[:space:]]*\)\s\s*/\1,/g`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will let you know after getting the chance to try it out.
Thanks also to whoever pointed out using sed instead of awk would be silly.