# ipython pandas TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delim-whitespace''

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ipython

While trying the ipython.org notebook, "INTRODUCTION TO PYTHON FOR DATA MINING"

The following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data-original",
               delim_whitespace = True, header=None,
               names = ['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'acceleration',
                        'model', 'origin', 'car_name'])
```

yields the following error:

```
 TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'delim-whitespace'
```

Unfortunately the dataset file itself is not really csv, and I don't know why they used read_csv() to get its data.

The data looks like this line:

```
 14.0   8.   454.0      220.0      4354.       9.0   70.  1.    "chevrolet impala"
```

The environment is python/2.7 on Debian stable w/ ipython 0.13.
After searching here, I realize it's mostly likely a version problem,
as the argument 'delim-whitespace' maybe in a later version of the pandas library, than the one available to the APT package manager.

I tried several workarounds, without success.

- First, I tried to upgrade pandas, by building from latest source, but i found i would end up with a cascade of other builds of dependencies whose versions need upgrading and could end up breaking the environment. E.g., I had to install Cython, then it reported it was again
  a version too old on the APT package manager, so I would have to rebuild Cython, + other libs/modules and so on.
- Then after looking at the API a bit, I tried using other arguments:
  using  delimiter = ' ' in the call to read_csv() caused 
  it to break up the strings inside quotes into several columns,

  ```
  ValueError: Expecting 9 columns, got 13 in row 0
  ```
- I tried using the     `read_csv()`     argument     `quotechar='"'`    , as documented in the API but again it was not recognized (unexpected keyword argument)
- Finally I tried using a different way to load the file,

  ```
  data = DataFrame()

  data.from_csv(url)
  ```

  I got,

  ```
  Out[18]: 
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Index: 405 entries, 15.0   8.   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70.  1."buick skylark 320" to 31.0   4.   119.0      82.00      2720.      19.4   82.  1.   "chevy s-10"
  Empty DataFrame

  In [19]: print(data.shape)
  (0, 9)
  ```
- alternatively, w/ sep argument to from_csv(),

  ```
  In [20]: data.from_csv(url,sep=' ')
  ```

  yields the error,

  ```
  ValueError: Expecting 31 columns, got 35 in row 1
  In [21]: print(data.shape)
  (0, 9)
  ```
- Also alternatively, with the same negative result:

  ```
  In [32]: data = DataFrame( columns = ['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'acceleration','model', 'origin', 'car_name'])

  In [33]: data.from_csv(url,sep=', \t')Out[33]: 
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Index: 405 entries, 15.0   8.   350.0      165.0      3693.      11.5   70.  1."buick skylark 320" to 31.0   4.   119.0      82.00      2720.      19.4   82.  1.   "chevy s-10"
  Empty DataFrame

  In [34]: data.head()
  Out[34]: 
  Empty DataFrame
  ```
- I tried using ipython3 instead,
  but it cannot find/load matplotlib as there is not matplotlib for python3 for my
  system.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only solution so far is to edit the data file so that it is actually comma-separated (see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061540/sed-replace-whitespace-characters-with-single-comma-except-inside-quotes) then make the call to the pd.read_csv() function without the delim_whitespace argument.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, the delim_whitespace parameter appears in the [Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) in the method summary but not the parameters list.  Try replacing it with `delimiter = r'\s+'`, which is equivalent to what I assume the authors meant.

CSV does refer to comma-separated values, but it's often used to refer to general delimited-text formats.  TSV (tab-separated values) is another variant; in this case it's basically whitespace-separated values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah that too is odd enough - especially in documentation !
Incidentally, the url of the notebook tried is http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Syrios12/learningwithdata/blob/master/Python_For_Data_Mining.ipynb

Comment: Using delimiter=r'\s+'  results in breaking up the quoted string into several columns again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses `delim_whitespace` but the error message says `delim-whitespace`. The former exists, the latter does not.

If the data file contains

```
 14.0   8.   454.0      220.0      4354.       9.0   70.  1.    "chevrolet impala"
```

and you define `data` with

```
data = pd.read_csv('data', delim_whitespace = True, header=None, names = ['mpg', 'cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'acceleration', 'model', 'origin', 'car_name'])
```

then the DataFrame does get parsed successfully:

```
   mpg  cylinders  displacement  horsepower  weight  acceleration  model  \
0   14          8           454         220    4354             9     70   

   origin          car_name  
0       1  chevrolet impala
```

So you just have change the hyphen to an underscore.

---

Note that when you specify `delim_whitespace=True`, the pure Python parser is used. In this case I don't think that is necessary. Using `delimiter=r'\s+'` as Steve Howard suggests would probably perform better. ([The source code says](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L177), "The C engine is faster while the python engine is
    currently more feature-complete", but I think [the only feature](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L321) that the python engine has that the C engine does not is `skipfooter`.)

Comment: Thanks for replying and the discrepancy between delim_whitespace and delim-whitespace ! The url for the notebook i was trying is 
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Syrios12/learningwithdata/blob/master/Python_For_Data_Mining.ipynb

Comment: I just tried it again, the delim-whitespace is a typo on my part, and is treated as an expression if used in the function call. Should i edit the original question or leave it with the typo? Thanks. Now trying delimiter's value suggested by unutbu...
ValueError: Expecting 9 columns, got 12 in row 0

And using the delim_whitespace=True gives the error in the original question, as the pandas being used (available through APT) is an older version.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I've attempted to write instructions for [how to install the the latest version of pandas here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28111323/190597).

Comment: Pandas version 0.8.0 here , the one through the APT repository (python-pandas pkg).. when i run $ sudo pip install --install-option="--prefix=" -U pandas i get ... ... File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (numpy 1.6.2 (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.7.0')) ---------------------------------------- Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in ~/build/pandas Storing complete log in ~/.pip/pip.log

Comment: My goodness that's old :) Are you willing to try the git/virtualenv instructions I [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28111323/190597)? It's a lot to download, but if successful, will allow you to always have the latest version of the entire NumPy-->Pandas stack.

Comment: Or, perhaps try the anaconda solution. You won't have complete freedom to choose the latest versions, but it looks easier to install and would get you over this parsing problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for [the instructions you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28111323/190597) to have the latest version with/in a virtualenv. i think that would be my option rather than the "easier" Anaconda.