# How can I install the latest versions of NumPy/Scipy/Matplotlib/IPython/Pandas on Ubuntu

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, pandas, scipy, ipython

Users [sometimes need to know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28101851/190597) how to install a newer version of Pandas than their OS package manager offers. Pandas requires NumPy, and works best with SciPy, Matplotlib and IPython.

How can I install the latest versions of NumPy/Scipy/Matplotlib/IPython/Pandas?

Comment: use [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [enthought canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/).

Comment: @unutbu, I think there's a difference between `latest version` and `development version`. In your first cw answer you described how to install the latest snapshot from git. Most users will probably prefer the lastest stable version. I think it may be a good idea to clarify that in your question.

Comment: @cel: Thanks for the comment. I've added instructions in the community wiki for how to select the latest version.

Comment: Now I started wondering if there is a PPA for this.

Answer (score 9):

Using Ubuntu, here is how to install the entire NumPy/Scipy/Matplotlib/IPython/Pandas
stack from Github in a virtualenv using Python2.7:

Note: The instructions below install the latest *development* version of each package. If you wish to install the latest tagged version, then after `git clone`, inspect the tags available with

```
git tag
```

and select the version you wish to install with

```
git checkout tag-name
```

#### Install [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

# edit ~/.bashrc to include
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# edit ~/.profile to include
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

# You may have to log out then log back in to make the change effective
```

#### Make a virtualenv

```
mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages dev
workon dev

# If you want to make this virtual environment your default Python,
# edit ~/.bashrc to include
workon dev
```

#### Add site-packages to sys.path:

```
add2virtualenv $USER/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

#### Install [Cython](http://cython.org/)

```
pip install -U Cython
```

#### Install [git](http://git-scm.com/)

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

#### Install [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)

```
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git

sudo apt-get install python-dev build-essential  
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev libatlas3gf-base

# ensure clean build
# this is not necessary the first time, but useful when upgrading
cd ~/src/numpy
/bin/rm -rf ~/src/numpy/build
cdsitepackages && /bin/rm -rf numpy numpy-*-py2.7.egg-info

cd ~/src/numpy
python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
python setup.py install
```

#### Install [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)

```
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git

# ensure clean build
cd ~/src/scipy
/bin/rm -rf ~/src/scipy/build
cdsitepackages && /bin/rm -rf scipy scipy-*-py2.7.egg-info

cd ~/src/scipy
git clean -xdf
python setup.py install
```

#### Install Matplotlib dependencies

```
pip install -U pyparsing
pip install -U six
pip install -U python-dateutil
pip install -U pytz
sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev
pip install -U tornado pygments pyzmq 
pip install -U nose
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-qt4-doc python-pyside python-cairo python-wxgtk2.8 python-gtk2 dvipng

apt-cache depends python-matplotlib | awk '/Depends:/{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --get-selections
sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib
```

#### Install [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

```
cd ~/src/
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

# ensure clean build
cd ~/src/matplotlib
/bin/rm -rf ~/src/matplotlib/build
cdsitepackages && /bin/rm -rf matplotlib* mpl_toolkits

# compile and install
cd ~/src/matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

#### Install [IPython](http://ipython.org/)

```
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git

# ensure clean build
cd ~/src/ipython
/bin/rm -rf ~/src/ipython/build
cdsitepackages && /bin/rm -rf ipython-*-py2.7.egg

cd ~/src/ipython
python setupegg.py install
```

#### Install [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
cd ~/src
git clone https://github.com/pydata/pandas.git
cd ~/src/pandas

# update
git fetch origin
git rebase --interactive origin/master

# ensure clean build and install
/bin/rm -rf ~/src/pandas/{build,dist} && cdsitepackages && /bin/rm -rf pandas* && cd ~/src/pandas && python setup.py build_ext --inplace && python setup.py install
```

---

#### Updating:

The advantage of
the git approach is that it provides a way to always keep these packages
up-to-date:

```
cd ~/src/package-name
git fetch origin
git rebase --interactive origin/master
```

Follow the instructions above to ensure a clean build, and then rebuild and
reinstall the package.

#### Shorthand for using pip with GitHub directly

The above steps to clone and install packages can be automated to an extent with pip.  For example, we can also install NumPy like this:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
```

The updating would then be just

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

`--force-reinstall` flag may be needed because pip checks the version from PyPI and doesn't update if the current version isn't smaller.

Comment: I think anaconda and canopy should be mentioned in the answer. That's a very convenient way of installing the scipy stack, especially for mac and windows users.

Comment: @cel: This is a community wiki. Please feel free to add information.

Comment: @gboffi: I forgot to include instructions on configuring virtualenv wrapper. I've edited the post above to show how.

Answer (score 8):

### Via the Anaconda distribution:

#### Download and install

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
chmod +x miniconda.sh
./miniconda.sh -b
export PATH=/home/travis/miniconda/bin:$PATH
conda update conda --yes
```

#### Install just the packages in the title in their own environment:

```
conda create --name myenv --yes python=3.4 pandas matplotlib ipython-notebook
source activate myenv
```

Note: I believe anaconda supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4.