# cannot use Python pandas package in Python 2.7 environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here is the error message and my simple program,

I am using pip install pandas to install pandas (I am using Mac OS),

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(['Dave', 'Cheng-Han', 'Udacity', 42, -1789710578])
print series

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/foo/PycharmProjects/PandasTest/PandasTest1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/PycharmProjects/PandasTest/PandasTest1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:23654)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Comment: Did you perhaps, upgrade your version of NumPy after installing pandas?

Comment: @unutbu, tried sudo -H pip --upgrade numpy, but it has errors like "no such option: --upgrade", any ideas how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant I think this error can occur if pandas was built with a different version of NumPy than the version you are currently running. I know how to [fix this on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28111323/190597) -- the solution is simply to recompile Pandas. But unfortunately I don't know how to modify those instructions for OSX. Moreover, there probably is a way fix this without manually  recompiling. But again, I don't know how it is done for OSX.